# Jquery ajax goes to error even though result came

Tags: spring, jquery, spring-mvc

I am using spring MVC and JQuery ajax. In one of my ajax call it returns large amount of data it nearly takes 5 minutes.
In Ajax method shows error even though the response came i checked it through firebug.
my ajax coding is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery("sampleSearch").click(function () {
                jQuery("body").addClass("loading");
                var formValues = jQuery('#sample-search-form').find(':input[value][value!=""]').serialize();
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/sample/user-byName",
                    data: formValues,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        jQuery('#json').val(JSON.stringify(data)).trigger('change');
                        jQuery('body').removeClass("loading");
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        alert('Error while request..' + e.toLocaleString());
                        jQuery('body').removeClass("loading");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

and in my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user-byName", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    String getUserByName(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
        String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
        Integer page = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page"));
        String resultJson = getUserByName(firstName, lastName, page);
        return resultJson;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increase the timeout for the request.

```
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/sample/user-byName",
                data: formValues,
                dataType: 'json',
                timeout: 600000,
                success: function (data) {
                    jQuery('#json').val(JSON.stringify(data)).trigger('change');
                    jQuery('body').removeClass("loading");
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    alert('Error while request..' + e.toLocaleString());
                    jQuery('body').removeClass("loading");
                }
            });
```

read more in the [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation

Comment: It says some time error even though i set timeout.In firebug it shows timeline as 20.45s. Why this happens